# Ajax requests ASAP right before </body>, or on document ready too?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, optimization

I'm optimizing a page, but I can't tell the difference in results between these (the first one is obviously faster, but I'm not sure if it slows the rendering of the page a little or something):

This one will start the request ASAP, and modify the DOM on document ready:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '/some-url',
    success: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // do something
        });
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

This one will start the request on document ready:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/some-url',
        success: function() {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Which one is recommended?

Comment: @whirlwin I'm already doing that in both cases. Or you mean after closing the tag?

Comment: No, you are already doing what I was trying to explain.

Comment: If you wait for document to be ready in success does that not possbily stall the page rendering until success is done due to the single thread nature of JavaScript?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl No, the page won't "wait" for it to be ready. In `success`, they would be binding a new "ready" event to the document. If the document is already ready by the time `success` executes, the function for `$(document).ready` will not execute.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I think you can't "wait" in Javascript, even if you want to.

Comment: @Ian: that is just wrong. `jQuery.fn.ready` will **always** fire, even if the DOM already was ready before.

Comment: @jAndy Yep, just figured that out. I had no idea. It's just not what I would "expect"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best practice here is to start the *Ajax request* as soon as possible, but start modifying the  DOM only when the document is ready (*DOMContentLoaded*). To do that, you might use jQuerys *Deferred objects* which are wired up with jQuerys extended *jXHR* objects.

```
<script>
    var req      = $.ajax({}),
        docReady = jQuery.Deferred();

    $(function() {
        docReady.resolve();
    });

    $.when( req, docReady ).done(function( data ) {
        // read the returned data and modify the DOM
    });
</script>
```

It would be a waste of time to wait for starting the request until the DOM is ready. The XHR request has no business and interest in whats going on with the DOM.

---

It just makes more sense to decouple those two things entirely. If for some reason the DOM needs a very long time before its ready, you didn't waste the time to let the *HTTP request* run and collect its data. The other way around, if the *request* is very slow, you would waste time aswell. So your current snippets are like

```
DOM ready    
           -> XHR request    
                          -> Do something useful
```

Whereas my example is like

```
DOM ready    
XHR request
            -> Do something useful as soon as the DOM and request are ready
```

Comment: Is this the same as my first example? I didn't know about when(req).done(), it looks "more correct".

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: well, it is somewhat close to your first example, but as you mentioned correctly, my example there is just more correct in terms of convenience. Its Pretty much starting the request and the listener for *DOMContentReady* simultaneously, but when the *ready event* fires and the request isn't finished yet, it'll still "wait" (careful, its just a callback) until the request finishes successful.

Comment: There are two differences between jAndy's and your code. The first is that you have yours right before `</body>`, so your `$.ajax` call starts a lot later (meaning it will finish a lot later). The second difference is that jAndy's code uses more jQuery methods to determine when the DOM is ready and the AJAX call has succeeded, and can cause more of a delay for when the `success` method runs (in the unlikely event that the AJAX request completes before all the binding is done). I think putting your first example on your page as soon as possible is the best solution

Comment: I still don't see the difference though. In my first example I'm not waiting for the document to be ready to start the ajax request. The document ready part occurs inside the callback I'm passing to ajax(). And it succeeds because like you said, if the document is already ready when I do the binding, the callback is executed.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: as I mentioned, in this particular example the difference is not huge. You should think about those two things in a more abstract manner. Both, are *asyncronous tasks*, you should not force them to run in order (why would you ?). They can run and exists in a *pseudo parallel mode*, by starting both tasks at the same time. So in general, whenever async tasks can co-exist, you shouldn't screw the show and run all the tasks sequentially. I don't know how to better explain it.

Comment: ChocoDeveloper the minor difference is that you test for success first, then wait for DOM ready. @Andy is doing the opposite, the result being the same (he could have done it the other way around too). If you had more than one ajax request you'd find Andy's approach cleaner.

Comment: @Christophe Yes that's how I see it, but he says I'm serializing things. The only order I have is in the bindings, but he has an order too (a more correct order maybe, because the document will be ready before the request is completed): he waits for the document to be ready, to do the binding of the request callback. I don't think doing the bindings takes measurable time anyway.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper you're correct, his comment should only apply to your second snippet, not both.

Comment: No, the comment is true for both versions. As I said, think more abstract, not specific. Think about async tasks which can run in parallel. With my versions, its possible that both tasks can finish at the same time, in both version of the OP, its likely that one tasks slows the the other, just because its not even allowed to execute before the other has finished.

Comment: @jAndy You are using $(function(){}), which is the same as document ready. So you can't bind the ajax callback until the document is ready.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: true, my example code was flawed that way. I was meaning a different story, I changed my example. Now, we can have callbacks for each single async task if we'd like to, and a combined "done" event.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: yeah.. was a hard road, but we got there :P. You *could* still add specialized events for each task/promise by calling `promiseObject.done(function)` or `promiseObject.fail(function)`, read more at jQuerys docs about *Deferred objects*.

Comment: @jAndy the new code is neat, but again it doesn't make much difference with the OP's first version. In that first snippet, only the success function (the equivalent of done()) is bound to DOM ready, not the XHR request itself, contrary to what your answer says.

Comment: @Christophe: Well I'm not sure if I can follow you here. If it takes like 10 seconds before `DOMContentLoaded` gets fired (for whatever crazy reason) we could share that timeline with my snippet for the time that the XHR requests needs to finish. Otherwise, it would still run sequentially.

Comment: @jAndy correct, I am just saying that the OP's first snippet will also do that.

Comment: @Christophe: but you are still wrong. `$(document).ready(fnc)` will do nothing else than adding a callback to the queue, which fires when `DOMContentLoaded` gets fired. So, again, if that takes a long period from that point on, you wasted all the time, the request already took to get there. I repeated that now for 5 times I guess :p

Comment: @jAndy right, you're repeating yourself and don't get my point. Your answer says that in both snippets the XHR request will happen AFTER the DOM is ready (see the arrow in your own diagram). This is correct for the second snippet but not for the first one. It seems that you are confusing the XHR request itself and the callback.

Comment: @Christophe: not sure if you're trolling or not now. That little example waterfall diagram is just showing the principle. As I said several times here, we are talking about async tasks, no specific things. Forget about *ready* or *XHR requests*. I really thought I made myself clear there.

Comment: @jAndy I don't think they're trolling. I feel the same way, but I've been holding back from commenting because it's still confusing me. I think we can ignore the second example the OP provided because we agree it's unnecessary to wait until the document is ready to make the AJAX call. I think your solution is great and would definitely accomplish everything efficiently. I think something important to point out is that with your solution, you are **always** creating 2 asynchronous tasks. If you use the OP's code, there's definitely 1 (the AJAX) and another only if DOM isn't ready at success

Comment: With the OP's code, they accomplish what you're doing, but in a "coupled" manner...it's the same thing as yours, but with the possibility of only 1 task. It's not like you'd ever notice the difference, but your example does use a lot more processing because as I said, it always binds the `ready` event, and then all the logic that jQuery must use for the `$.when` and `.done`. By "a lot", I mean the fact that both snippets call `$.ajax` and `$(document).ready`, but yours does more...while they accomplish the same.

Comment: Since the `$(document).ready` is inside of `success`, it's the "same" as `$.when( req )`. Then, as the next sequential thing, binding `$(document).ready` accomplishes `$.when( docReady )`. But again, it doesn't use the extra logic for actually creating a deferred object and binding the `when` and `done` stuff. And finally, the OP's code only worries about handling the DOM being ready **if** the AJAX request is a **success**. With your code, **everything** (bindings and logic) is **always** done.

Comment: @Ian thx for jumping in :-) I realized later that some of the confusion also comes from the </body> tag (cf. my comment under your own answer).

Comment: @Ian: yes, I guess I needed a couple of hours sleep to realize what @Christophe tried to tell me all the time. `$.fn.ready` is not triggering any process, just binding (thats where my confusion came from). The abstract example I was talking about is only true, if we're deadling with multiple async processes, which start by calling something.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$.ajax` doesn't depend on the DOM in any way, there's no reason why you can't call it as soon as possible. In that case, I would put it in the `<head>` section and call it as soon as its dependent script/script files are done (meaning at least jQuery library). Firing the AJAX request sooner means the response has the ability to come back sooner - it may not be the case that it actually happens, but that's not important.

Checking to sure the DOM is ready inside of `success` is necessary for you, and it's the quickest way for your code to execute. Using `$.when( req ).done(function () {})` creates 2 more jQuery method calls that may or may not significantly delay the execution of your `success` code - it will delay it, but it will probably be insignificant.

Also, your example where you use `document.ready` in your `success` method creates the **possibility** that the DOM is ready and can execute immediately (in the case that the AJAX request completes before the DOM is fully loaded, which I wouldn't expect). In jAndy's example where `document.ready` runs immediately after `$.ajax`, it **guarantees** that it will bind an event handler for the document being ready...which means it has to be stored (causing the DOM to be ready later) and then looked up later when the event occurs, and executed. Again, the difference is **possibility** vs. **guarantee**...and all is probably insignificant (as long as you don't use your second example).

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's ok to execute something before the end of the body? I understand I'm only doing bindings, but I thought this was kind of a no brainer, a golden rule.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking if it's okay to run Javascript anywhere just before `</body>`? Javascript can be run anywhere in the head and body, I believe. But of course, a DOM element cannot be manipulated until it is ready (which is immediately after it is parsed on the page). Putting things at the end of the body is an organizational way of making sure all of the elements in the body are ready and keeps all Javascript code together.

Comment: Yes I always read that for optimization (not just organization), you have to put all your js right before </body>, never in the middle of the body, or in the head. Not sure exactly why.

Comment: So I think the reason for that is because Javascript blocks DOM parsing/rendering. As the page is parsed from top to bottom, everything is processed. So as you go from top to bottom, you may get some HTML here, some Javascript there, and I'm not sure about CSS. But anyways, because of these little delays here and there of the Javascript executing (even if it's simply binding a function for an event), it **may** cause the page to not render as nicely as it could if you put all Javascript after you know all elements are ready (at the end of the body).

Comment: Organizationally, it's nice. It's up to you if you mind separating your Javascript - some in the head, some at the end of the body, some in the middle of the body if necessary. Something like an asynchronous HTTP request will not slow you down that much, as the only delay it takes is setting it up and sending it off...the response is asynchronous, so the page is allowed to continue rendering instead of wait for the response. Same with the event binding for `document.ready` - all jQuery does is store a reference to the function you want it to execute for the event - the function executes later.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper "you have to put all your js right before </body>" => I think this is an "old" rule to avoid blocking page rendering. Now that async coding has become the norm (AMD, ajax, deferred) it's not so true anymore.

Answer (score -2):

In this simple example, both versions should do. Which one is better depends on your page and other scripts.
If your script is a little more complex, and you need to pass data to the ajax-request which has to be fetched from the page, and your page is not ready at that moment - you will have an error.

Another thing is, that any script on your page will block the browser while it is processed, so a more complex code without doc-ready around it may lead to a short stop in the page-render-process.
In most cases I prefer to let the browser to load all HTML, CSS and the JS - and after that start my progressive enhancement and loading of additional content.

But again - in this simple case - I don't see much of a difference.